# how to bind url to variable in php

Tags: php

I want to bind the complete URL in a PHP variable.

My URL looks like this: `http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin`.

To get the URL I use following:

```
http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

and for the hash value is use this JS:

```
document.write(window.location.hash);
```

So my PHP variable looks like below:

```
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"."<script>document.write(window.location.hash);</script>";
```

When I echo the `$current_url` I get this output: `http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin`.

Now I want to have a check on the current URL:

```
if ($current_url != "http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin") {
    echo "you are NOT the admin";
}
else {
    echo "you are the admin";
}
```

Unfortunately, even when the URL is exactly the same, he keeps hanging on: "you are NOT the admin".

What is going wrong here?

Comment: But you wrote that the `$current_url` contains `http://develop.example.com/spf<script>document.write(window.location.hash);</script>` which obviously isn't the same as `http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin`. Or I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes thats probably the problem: i want to bind the hash (#users/admin) to the php variable. How can i do that? The javascript is supposed to be executed and the value should be in the php variable

Comment: What? How? JavaScript is executed in a browser, way long after PHP execution finished and webserver process ended. How would you like to execute that JavaScript using the PHP? It doesn't know anything about that. You should learn how the client-server works first, that's fundamental to be able to develop web applications.

Comment: FYI - this doesn't look like a very secure method for determining if someone is an admin.  Anyone can change the url so it looks like they are an admin.

Comment: Also check how the [Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (that's what you call *hash* works. It's not sent to the server at all, so it's not a good idea to work with that on the server. You can create a JavaScript which sends with the request, but you will run into *a lot* of problems.

Comment: this is not about securing. I was just checking if i can do a check on a url:I did check the output of _$current_url_ and he gives me this output: http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin So the content of the variable is correct

Comment: But fragment is very special part of the URL. It usually specifies a part of the page, so it can change without doing any request. So it doesn't make a sense to work with that on the server.

Comment: @JackMaessen How it can be correct, when it contains URL + text `<script>document.write(window.location.hash);</script>`? That doesn't make a sense. Again, **the `$current_url` contains `http://develop.example.com/spf<script>document.write(window.location.hash);</sc‌​ript>`** which **is not** the same as `http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin`.

Comment: Well what i do not understand: when i echo $current_url he produces this: http://develop.example.com/spf#users/admin But when i do the check with the if/else loop, he keeps hanging on "you are NOT the admin" while it is exact the same

Comment: How are you checking the content of `$current_url` variable? I guess you just watch the web page, right? Try to stop for a while and start to think about that. Will you see, what it really contains when the browser interprets the HTML? (Hint: of course not) Open the page source and check how it looks there. It's not the same, right?

Comment: Dawid is right.  The PHP executes before the page is rendered to the client.  You can't get a value from JavaScript at that point.  JavaScript doesn't run until the page renders at the client.

Comment: @JackMaessen You should check variable values in the watch feature of the debugger, echoing it and watching interpreted result in a browser says you have no clue how elementary parts of web applications work. Client/server, HTML interpretation, server-side and client-side execution - those are fundamental things you should know before you even start to develop the "Hello world" web application. Otherwise, you will ask such questions, which doesn't make a sense.

Comment: You are right!! I looked into the source and url is http://example.com/spf and after it is the javascript and then is at least #users/admin I do understand now! Thanks for this hint

Comment: Of course, that's how HTML rendering works. I really advise you to stop now, read the basics first (server/client, server-side/client-side execution, HTTP, PHP, HTML, JavaScript) and then start with something easier. You're trying to develop an application which uses a lot of different technologies without knowing how they work. Everyone has to start somehow, nobody knows everything from the begining.

Comment: Besides Serverside/Clientside, another fundamental misunderstanding is, `#hashtag` is not part of the HTTP protocol, it's something that happens in the browser, not on the server. It's ment to describe anchors inside of html, not http.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following script and your code is correct but the problem is "document.write(window.location.hash);" this code remove it then run

```
   <?php
    $current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


    $match="http://localhost:900/at/";
    // echo base64_encode($current_url);

    // echo "<br>";

    // echo base64_encode($match) ;


    if ($current_url==$match) {

        echo "you are the admin";

    }
    else {

     echo "you are NOT the admin";
    }


    ?>
```